# Axios returns isAxiosError, but the response.status is 200

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, axios

I am trying to resolve a promise because I am getting a code 200 and a response.data is not undefined, but because of code is "ERR_BAD_OPTION" isAxiosError is set to true, and the promise gets rejected.
How can I resolve it?

This is what response looks like

```
  {
    "code": "ERR_BAD_OPTION",
    "isAxiosError": true,
    "request: {...}
    "response": {
      "config": {...},
      "data": {...} , 
      "headers": AxiosHeaders {}
      "ok": true, 
      "status": 200,
    }
...
}
```

This is my code:

```
import axios, { AxiosError, AxiosRequestConfig, AxiosResponse, isAxiosError } from 'axios'
import fetchAdapter from '@haverstack/axios-fetch-adapter'

export interface InterceptorError extends AxiosError {
  handleErrorInComponent?: boolean
}


export const api = axios.create({
  adapter: fetchAdapter, // necessary for PWA service worker.
})

export const getBaseURL = (): string => ('urlString')

const requestInterceptor = (request: AxiosRequestConfig): AxiosRequestConfig => {
  addBearerTokenToRequest(request)

  return request
}

const handleErrors = (error: InterceptorError | string[]) => {

  if (isAxiosError(error)) showErrorToast(translate('ui.general.connection.httpError'))
  else {
    // Throw status code 200 errors back to component catch.
    throw error
  }

  return error
}

const hasError = (response: AxiosResponse): boolean => {
  return !!response?.data?.error
}

const responseInterceptor = async (response: AxiosResponse): Promise<AxiosResponse> => {
  if (hasError(response)) handleErrors(response.data.error)

  return response.data.result
}

const errorInterceptor = async (error: InterceptorError): Promise<Error> => {

return Promise.reject(handleErrors(error)) // Handle error in interceptor
}

api.interceptors.request.use(requestInterceptor, errorInterceptor)
api.interceptors.response.use(responseInterceptor, errorInterceptor)
```

Comment: HTTP errors are below the application layer. An HTTP request is a "success" if the client issues a request and the server responds with a payload. An application-level error does not make the HTTP transaction a failure.